# backslash at end of string

Tags: fortran, doxygen

Does anybody know how to use Doxygen to document Fortran code in which a character array is assigned a string that terminates in a backslash. I tried it with the following code with Doxygen version 1.6.1 :

```
program test
  character(80) :: test_char
  test_char = '\\test\test\'
  stop
end program test
```

and got the error: "Error in file test.f90 line: 9, state: 20"

Comment: Is there an error code or a specific error diagnostic?  That just says *where* there is an error.

Comment: @wallyk there is no error code or specific error diagnostic. I however know that the problem is with the trailing backslash since Doxygen runs ok when I remove it. This trailing backslash is however required and I thus can't remove it from my code

Comment: Perhaps `test_char = '\\test\test'//char(ichar('\'))` would be a useable kludge ?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Many, by default, use back slash as an escape sequence in character strings, but there may well be a compiler flag to return them to sanity.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a doxygen 1.6.1 bug (doxygen commands could start with [backslash](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html) and `\'` is probably wrongly parsed).

The latest version of doxygen is 1.8.7, so first step is to update and try with that.

In case it does not help, you can use custom FILTER to remove backslash characters from strings in your code.

Comment: This is a known problem in doxygen and still existing in version 1.8.7 the backslash is seen as escaping the ' See Bug 596872 - Fortran: Backslashes in literals are always treated as special chars

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I ended up using the following solution:

```
program test
  character(80) :: test_char
  character(2)  :: bckslsh = '\\'

  test_char = '\\test\test'//bckslsh(1:1)

  stop
end program test
```